# Cards with different numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I feel like the best way to do this problem is by using recursion. First, find how many ways there is to have 3 distinct numbers on the table. Choosing those 3 numbers, you have 4 choose 3 ways. I don’t know how to go on from there.

Comment: $N_3=2 \cdot (N_2)$

Comment: ? Can u explain on what ur saying?

Comment: $N_x$ denotes number of $x$ distinct cards, Now $N_3$ is equal to $N_2 \cdot 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to count the order in which there is a moment we have at least 3 distinct numbers. Let us define $a,b,c,d$ as a permutation of $1,2,3,4$ such that $a,b,c$ are the first 3 distinct number to appear on the table.

The order must be:

$ddabc...,dadbc...,addbc...$ where $...$ is a permutation of $a,b,c$ or $abc...$ where $...$ is a pernutation of $a,b,c,d,d$

there are $4!\times 3\times 3!+4!\times \frac{5!}{2}=1872$ orderings if the cards with equal number are indistinguishable. Otherwise, multiply by $2^{4}$

Also, the total number of orderings is $8!$ if cards with equal number is distinguished and $\frac{8!}{2^{4}}$ otherwise

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. $ddabc \ldots$ isn't allowed since you will have $a,b,c$ on the table.

Comment: @CalvinLin I was trying to calculate the number of orderings which will leave at least 3 distinct card on table. then subtract this from total number of orderings to obtain the answer

Comment: Ah. How do we know that's all the cases?  And also, did you include cases where we see all 4 on the table? (Since your listed cases result in $d$ being removed.)

Comment: @CalvinLin my idea is to define $a,b,c$ as the first 3 distinct numbers appear at the same time on the table. the first 3 case only have max 3 distinct numbers on the table which must be $a,b,c$ by definition. the case $abc...$ includes scenario in which we have 4 distinct numbers i.e. in which we pull $abcd...$